# How add conditional required field

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

**Need**:

If we select a value in a drop-down list field(A), then we need to display and set as required field(B).

**Note**: the field(B) is a date range.

I tried to add states with a hook form alter

```
$form['field_b']['#states'] = [
      'visible' => [
        ':input[name="field_a"]' => ['!value' => '_none']
      ],
      'required' => [
        ':input[name="field_a"]' => ['!value' => '_none'],
      ],
  ];
```

As you see I use: '!value' to negate a value and '_none' for no value. So, It will not be required if there is no value selected

**This code didn't work.** It display the field B, but it is not mandatory.

We found that there is an issue with core
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2855139

At the end issue was closed, but it didn't work for us. It worked with texte fields but not for our rage date.

Answer (score 1):

For required state you have to target the actual input as mentioned in [Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/conditional-form-fields#staterequired)

Example:

```
$form['field_name']['widget']['0']['target_id'['#states'] = [
  'required' => [
    ':input[name="input_name"]' => ['value' => 'value']
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if dont want to use [conditional_fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module and only [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/conditional-fields) core
You can do it, but required field have sometime a little bug.

In the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2855139) someone take some code from conditional_fields that fix this issue, and use it.

your_module/js/conditional_fields.js

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

// Fix core's required handling.
$(document).bind('state:required', function (e) {
  if (e.trigger) {
    var fields = $(e.target).find('input, select, textarea, fieldset');
    fields.each(function() {
      var label = 'label' + (this.id ? '[for=' + this.id + ']' : '');
      var $field_labels = $(e.target).find(label);
      var $fieldset_legends = $(e.target).find('legend span.fieldset-legend');
      var $labels = $field_labels.add($fieldset_legends);
      if (e.value) {
        $(this).attr({ required: 'required', 'aria-required': 'aria-required' });
        $labels.each(function() {
          $(this).addClass('js-form-required form-required');
        });
      } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('required aria-required');
        $labels.each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('js-form-required form-required');
        });
      }
    })
  }
});

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

In your_module.module in a form alter add:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'your_module/conditional_fields';

$form['field_b']['#states'] = [
      'visible' => [
        ':input[name="field_a"]' => ['!value' => '_none']
      ],
      'required' => [
        ':input[name="field_a"]' => ['!value' => '_none'],
      ],
  ];
```

**Don't forget add the js code in your_module.libraries.yml file**

[Adding JS to a Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module)

With our above code it worked!.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9, there's no need to add so much custom code like the other answer.

Here's an easy example, with the condition being a checkbox checked/unchecked:

```php
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('my_module.settings');

    $form['api'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $this->t('Use the API'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Uncheck to skip the API call and fall back to a hard-coded response.'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('api'),
    ];

    $form['appid'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('API Key'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('appid'),
      '#description' => $this->t('The API key'),
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="api"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
        ],
        'required' => [
          ':input[name="api"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }
```

- You can use `value` instead of `checked`, or some other property.
- Use `!` to negate it, like `!value`
- Use `_none` to represent no value, so use `['!value' => '_none']` to ensure there's a value

Answer (score 0):

So for fields having required attribute in widget array, You may use below code :

```
  $form['field_name']['widget']['#states'] = [
    'required' => [
      ':input[name="conditional_field_name[$option_id]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
    ],
  ]
  //Please vote if it works.
```